# SQL - Copy and replace data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm having trouble with copying data from a table with the same structure to another table with the same first column. I have 2 tables. One is STANDARD, the other one is called W2.

I then choose a name, for example Test.

I want to copy the values except for the name from the STANDARD table into the W2 table. So replace those values. As you can see the values of Test are different in the W2 table. I want to replace those values with the values from STANDARD.

STANDARD:

[image: STANDARD Table image]

W3:

[image: W2 Table image]

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Please add table description sample data and what you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried this far? Something like "INSERT INTO w2 SELECT ... FROM STANDARD WHERE ..."?

Comment: What database system are you using? Please add a suitable tag, e.g. `mysql`.

Comment: I don't want it to add rows. I want it to update them. I edited the post for better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Update w2 set
    Maandag = (SELECT Maandag From STANDARD a where w2.id = a.id),
    Dinsdag = (SELECT Dinsdag From STANDARD a where w2.id = a.id)
    Etc....
Where w2.id = 'test'
```

Comment: This worked but I want it to only affect one row. SO for example the row where ID='Test'.

Comment: If it worked, can you please mark this as the answer